# Laying cable across a river

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

This is a very interesting calculus word problem that I came across in an old textbook of mine. So I know its got something to do with minimising distance, but other than that, the textbook gave no hints really and I'm really not sure about how to approach it. However, I did manage to make a picture or diagram of it.

[image]

Any guidance hints or help would be truly greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance :) So anyway, here the problem goes:

> A power house, $P$, is on one bank of a straight river $200\textrm{ m}$ wide, 
>   and a factory, $F$, is on the opposite bank $400\textrm{ m}$ downstream from $P$.
>
> The cable has to be taken across the river,
>   under water at a cost of $\text{\$}6/\textrm{m}$.
>
> On land the cost is $\text{\$}3/\textrm{m}$.
>
> What path should be chosen so that the cost is minimized?

**Edit: Thanks guys, I think I found out the answer. I shall post it on MSE.**

Comment: @ZevChonoles Wow! Thanks so much for the edits! Unfortunately I'm a noob at MSE too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here is the diagram:

Please note the difference between *P* and *P'*

[image]

Let's look at the extreme cases first:

Straight across the river is $ \$200 m \cdot \$ 6m = \$1200$

$+  400 m  \ \text{on land} \cdot  \$ 3m = \$1200$

Total: $ \$ 2400$

If we go diagonal, then by Pythagoras,
it's $200 \sqrt 5 m \cdot \$6m = 1200 \sqrt 5 \approx \$2683$

Let the point straight across from P be P'.

Let's choose a landfall point Q, somewhere P' and F.

Let distance from P' to Q be q.

So total distance is

$\sqrt{200² + q²}$ (diagonal under the river) + 400 - q (on land)

Cost is $6 \cdot \sqrt{200² + q²} + 3 \cdot (400 - q)$

We want to minimize that.

First we can divide by 3 -- same value for q will be maximum.

$2 \cdot \sqrt{200² + q²} + 400 - q$

Derivative is

$2q \cdot \sqrt{200² + q²} - 1$

We set that to 0

$2q \cdot \sqrt{40000+q²} = 1$

$2q = \sqrt{40000+q²}$

Square:

$4 q² = 40000 + q^2$

$3 q² = 40000$

$q = 200 \sqrt 3$

Length under water is then $400 \sqrt 3  \approx 231$

and length on land is $400 - 200 \sqrt 3  \approx 284$

Cost is $6 \cdot 400\sqrt 3 + 3 (400 - 200\sqrt 3) = \$2239.23$

The triangle $P-P'-Q$ has sides $200 - 200\sqrt 3 - 400  \sqrt 3$

and therefore it is a 30-60-90 triangle.

The angle QPQ' = 30°.

Comment: I have done my last edit. Now you can replace the asterixs.

Comment: @calculus thank you so much.

Answer (score 7):

Let me just get you started on the problem.

Let $x$ be the length of the cable on land, and $y$ be the length of the underwater cable.

Then, the cost, obviously, is $$C(x,y)=3x+6y$$

Can we find any other connection between $x$ and $y$? Of course we can! We know that $y$ is the hypothenuse of a right angled triangle. One of its sides is the width of the river, and the other is $400 - x$, meaning that $$y^2=200^2 + (400-x)^2$$

From these two equations (and the fact that $y>0$), you can determine the cost of the cable as a function of $x$, i.e. you get $C(x)$ which is a nice function of $x$. Then, all you have to do is find its minimum.

Comment: Oh ok thanks so much that helps a lot.

Comment: Find angle as a function of q/w and, w/ FP' and cost ratio, where w is river width.That will give solution for all such problems.

Comment: @Narasimham Yes of course, thank you.

Answer (score 7):

We can borrow the [optical refraction formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refraction)

Here the cost of cable can be considered to be the cost of time for light to go through water. Light always takes the fastest route.

let $\theta$ be the angel between cable and the banks, then we must have $\cos{\theta}=\frac{3}{6}*\cos{0}=\frac{1}{2}$. So $\theta=\frac{\pi}{6}$.

Comment: This just goes to show that there appear to many different ways to approach this problem, although I do not know the optical refraction formula.

Comment: But my solution is the best.:) I did try all those analytical with differentiation approaches. They all give the correct answer, but they are all tedious and lack natural beauty.

Comment: There is no such thing as "your solution is the best." They are simply different ways to approach the problem.

Comment: Usually, I would agree, but in this case, there is this such thing as "the best approach".

Comment: Very well, I upvoted your post...Have a look at my answer below and see if that is "tedious". I find it rather fun. But then again, this is a fun question.

Comment: I quite like the use of optical laws here. A more common problem is that of a lifeguard on a beach trying to reach a swimmer needing help at $P$ starting from his watchtower at $F$ and minimizing the time he needs. But calling it "the best" method may be a bit cocky :-) After all, what is best for the reader depends on the reader's background.

Comment: Nothing necessarily wrong in blowing one's own trumpet (if it has a good tune to it). Nevertheless, it will irritate some, so may backfire. I quite understand the bubbling joy caused by coming up with a clever solution - those bubbles will come to the surface. Try to keep the lid on it though. Plenty of clever folks around here.

Comment: Cool it, guys. I used my superpowers and deleted some comments. So far it's ok, but this can take a nasty turn. Just let it rest.

Comment: No worries. I was just intentionally being dramatic...joking tones really don't travel well in texts. Apologies.

Comment: Your solution would perhaps have been the best, if it had bothered to prove this optical refraction formula. But you don't have to do that now -- see [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1329881/1508).

Comment: Your solution is the most elegant and the worst, depending on how you look at it. It is very elegant, it is also correct, but, at the end of the day, the solution is invalid. In order for it to be valid, you should prove that the optical refraction formula applies in this case.

Comment: @5xum, Of course it applies, the fraction formula is solving exactly the optimization problem of how light reaches a certain point in shortest time when it travels in different speeds in different materials, except the "time" is "money" here.

Comment: @Indominus Yes, I agree. But in order for this proof to be rigorous, a couple more lines of text are required, and if a student has no knowledge about that subject, the solution is no longer elegant or "best".

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: The optical refraction formula is usually (in my experience, at least) proved by the same methods in other answers to this post, in conjunction with Fermat's principle.

Comment: @anomaly Yes that would make sense.

Comment: @anomaly: If you derive it using [Huygens' principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huygens%E2%80%93Fresnel_principle) you only need basic trig. No calculus or such. Actually I think it is more natural to think of Fermat's principle as a consequence of Huygens, but I'm not an expert in teaching optics :-)

Answer (score 3):

Let $\theta$ be angle $P'PQ$. Then $PQ = 200\sec\theta$, and $FQ = 400 - 200\tan\theta$. We want to minimise the cost, which is
$$C(\theta)=6PQ+3FQ = 1200\sec\theta+1200-600\tan\theta$$
The derivative is
$$\frac{dC}{d\theta} = 1200\sec\theta\tan\theta - 600\sec^2\theta$$
and setting this to zero gives $2\tan\theta=\sec\theta$, or $\sin\theta=\frac12$.

Answer (score 2):

The length between P and Q is $\sqrt{q^2+200^2}$ ([pythagorean theorem](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem))

And the distance between F and Q is $400-q$

Therefore the cost function is $C(q)=6 \cdot \sqrt{q^2+200^2}+3\cdot (400-q)$

Take the derivative and set it equal to zero. Then solve for q.

Comment: Yes that is what I did...see my answer to my own question above.

Comment: I see. Your q is right.

Comment: Thank you...However, because I am a noob, I do not know how to use the square root signs...If possible, could you edit my answer to use the appropriate symbols?

Comment: Kindly, thank you for your edits.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Oh dear, could you please have a look at the first couple lines of my answer? There's something very rotten at the core I'm afraid.

Comment: I would also like to replace all the asterix with dots in the middle or x symbols...How do you do that?

Comment: Im still working on the first lines. After that you can replace * by \cdot But only, if it is inside the two $. And do not mix it up with \$. \$ is the code for  the dollar sign.

Comment: Oh ok thanks so much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24943/discussion-between-anonymous-and-calculus).

Answer (score 1):

You want to minimise the sum of the line across the water and the line along the river bank, each weighted by the unit cost for each section.
Assuming the cable can only be run in a straight line across the river, your objective function would be:

$$Cost=6\times\sqrt{200^2+q^2}+3\times(400-q)$$
To minimise, take the first derivative with respect to q and let it equal zero. Solve for q. Note the constraint that $q>=0$. Check for a minimum turning point using the second derivative with respect to q.